# Add password to a Java keytool's keystore that doesn't have any password

Tags: java

JDK: Corretto 1.8

Platform: macOS Big Sur

I am attempting to add an existing keystore without an existing password. For example, I can list as:

```
keytool -list  -keystore debug.keystore
Enter keystore password:

*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
* The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
* you must provide your keystore password.                  *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************

Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

somekey, 23/09/2021, PrivateKeyEntry,
```

However, when adding a password, I get

```
keytool -storepasswd -keystore debug.keystore
Enter keystore password: <blank password>
Keystore password is too short - must be at least 6 characters
```

So it seems, that if there is no initial password, you can't set one subsequently. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, it appears that you can list the entries without a valid password. So key there might be a password afternoon

Comment: The warning means that there *is* a password and you didn't supply one. You can list entries without a password, and retrieve certificates, but you can't get private key entries.

Comment: Ah yeah, after posting this question I have learned that. Feel free to add your comment as a answer.